# Auto Incrementing primary key

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL work bench where the table has an auto generated and auto incremented primary key. Now it increments from the last key by 1:

> next-key = last-key +1

I wold like to increment this number by 100:

> next-key = last-key + 100

Is there a way to do this in workbench? For the column where the primary key is, there is an option to put in a default expression, if this is where it's done what would the expression look like.

A sample would be helpful.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? [Is it possible to set auto-increment-increment by 10 for only one table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163248/is-it-possible-to-set-auto-increment-increment-by-10-for-only-one-table)

Comment: Furthermore, why do you think you need this behavior in your auto increment column?

Comment: make another column and use default expression in there

Answer (score 1):

You can do that at the creation of your table or after by a ALTER TABLE.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Ref. MySQL guide: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the starting value to 100 as follows

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

But to increment this number by 100, You need to edit the global variable -  auto_increment_increment in your mysql server.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment

But this change will effect all the tables in your database server.